# Trigger a non-zero exit code when I break out of a loop

Tags: bash, exit-status

I'd like to run a series of tasks but stop should any of them fail, hence I've written (something like):

```
for task in [TASKS]; do
  process "$task" || break
  commit "$task"
done
```

This works fine, but (as [specified](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html)) the exit status of this loop is zero even if we break early. Ideally `break`-ing would be able to convey the failure.

I know returning `0` is the documented behavior of `break`, but I'm curious if there are any relatively clean workarounds. The best I can imagine is wrapping this in a function and setting a `didBreak` variable, and using that as the exit status (of the function). It'd work, but it feels overly-complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `! break` works in many shells (all but the pdksh based ones and the `sh` of FreeBSD ([by](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02755.html) [design](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=249407)) in my tests):

```
$ zsh -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ bash -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ ksh88 -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ ksh93 -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ dash -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ yash -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ bosh -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
1
$ pdksh -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
0
$ mksh -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
0
$ posh -c 'for i in x; do ! break; echo "$i"; done'; echo "$?"
0
```

Note that it doesn't trigger `errexit` in any of them.

It was [discussed on the austin-group (the body behind POSIX) mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02741.html) last year. The discussion (which involved the maintainers of `bosh`, FreeBSD `sh` and NetBSD `sh`) died out before a consensus was reached, but the prevalent view seemed to be that POSIX required that behaviour as `!` is documented as negating the exit status of commands and `break` is a special builtin command that exits with 0 exit status.

But if you apply the same reasoning to `return` for instance, you'll see that fewer shells comply.

In `zsh`, you can use `return` in an anonymous function instead of `break`:

```
$ () for i in x y; do echo $i; return 1; done
x
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Hah that's great! TIL. Is this a documented feature at all, or just a total coincidence that it works in most shells? `bash --posix` also works this way.

Comment: @dimo414, see edit for the POSIX view on that.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be possible to just wrap it in a function (not an anonymous function) and use `return 1` from there?  Or is that not POSIX-compliant?

Comment: @Wildcard, yes using a function would be an obvious way to do it. See also [this message of mine in the aforementioned discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02742.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that context! Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
failed=false
for task in "${tasks[@]}"; do
  if ! process "$task"; then
      failed=true
      break
  fi
  commit "$task"
done

if "$failed"; then
   echo "Failed something" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm envisioning (aside from wrapping it in a function), but it feels kludgy to me. Maybe that's the best I can do, though.

Comment: @dimo414 Doesn't feel too kludgy to me. You could even use `failed="$t"` or something to later be able to tell what task it was that failed.

Comment: `process` prints enough information to describe what went wrong; all that's missing is stopping after the loop terminates-early. You're right it's not that bad, I just don't love the separation.

Answer (score 0):

My imagined solution is:

```
run_til_failure() {
  local didBreak=0
  for task in [TASKS]; do
    process "$task" || { didBreak=1; break; }
    commit "$task"
  done
  local loopExit=$?
  if (( loopExit )); then return $loopExit; fi
  return $didBreak
}
```